# Unable use json_extract with a multi-nested json string into MySQL table

Tags: mysql

[multi-nested-json-object screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CypRO.png)

I have json data in a table in MySQL which has an object nested inside an object (created by Wordpress) which I need to get the oid and product_id (see screenshot). My issue is that the object "eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF" is an auto-generated string from a wordpress plugin helping with listing users who have abandoned their cart.

Imagine a table with a single column in MySQL that looks like this...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEctz.png)

```
column_name: abandoned_cart
row1: {"cart":{"eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF":{"oid":"tUWTDArmqojehvsGc","key":"eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF","product_id":48337,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"BzcZvMnrKFUZtBftM","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":88,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":88,"line_tax":0}}}
row2: {"cart":{"AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV":{"oid":"XrsAwnqxspvqAvYGv","key":"AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV","product_id":7453,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"RoUNjJxfhqeveEHJW","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":25,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":25,"line_tax":0}}}
```

I can use json_extract to get the first object using the following query ... [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c0FH.png)

```
select
json_extract(abandoned_cart_info, '$.cart') cart
from json.abandoned_cart;
```

My results look like this... which is correct... [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c0FH.png)

```
column_name: cart
row1: {"eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF":{"oid":"tUWTDArmqojehvsGc","key":"eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF","product_id":48337,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"BzcZvMnrKFUZtBftM","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":88,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":88,"line_tax":0}}
row2: {"AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV":{"oid":"XrsAwnqxspvqAvYGv","key":"AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV","product_id":7453,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"RoUNjJxfhqeveEHJW","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":25,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":25,"line_tax":0}}
```

My question is how can I use json_extract for the auto-generated key (e.g. eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF and AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV and so on..) to get the oid and product_id?

```
select
    json_extract(abandoned_cart_info, '$.eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF.oid') oid,
    json_extract(abandoned_cart_info, '$.eBuefzeXhMBTVWFyF.product_id') product_id,
    json_extract(abandoned_cart_info, '$.AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV.oid') oid,
    json_extract(abandoned_cart_info, '$.AkLwfKZzyUwCcvvqV.product_id') product_id,

from json.abandoned_cart;
```

The above query is obviously not suffice because the key is auto-generated. What am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract):

```
SELECT
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_KEYS(JSON_EXTRACT(abandoned_cart_info, '$.cart')), '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS obj_key,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(abandoned_cart_info, '$.cart.*.oid'), '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS oid,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(abandoned_cart_info, '$.cart.*.product_id'), '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS product_id
FROM abandoned_cart;
```

... or using `->>`:

```
SELECT
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_KEYS(abandoned_cart_info->>'$.cart'), '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS obj_key,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(abandoned_cart_info->>'$.cart.*.oid', '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS oid,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(REGEXP_REPLACE(abandoned_cart_info->>'$.cart.*.product_id', '^\\[|\\]$', '')) AS product_id
FROM abandoned_cart;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1affeb0d0f15b0c221fdc796dfe637c3)